# Issue with QuantLib's BondFunctions.zSpread using RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle in Python

Tags: programming, quantlib

I'm using QuantLib in Python to calculate the z-spread of a bond. I have a `RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle` for the yield curve, but I'm getting a **TypeError** when I try to pass this handle to the `ql.BondFunctions.zSpread()` function.

```
Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'BondFunctions_zSpread'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    BondFunctions::zSpread(Bond const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency,Date,Real,Size,Rate)
    BondFunctions::zSpread(Bond const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency,Date,Real,Size)
    BondFunctions::zSpread(Bond const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency,Date,Real)
    BondFunctions::zSpread(Bond const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency,Date)
    BondFunctions::zSpread(Bond const &,Real,ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure > const &,DayCounter const &,Compounding,Frequency)
```

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
z_spread = ql.BondFunctions.zSpread(self.bond,bond_dirty_price, self.yield_curve , ql.SimpleDayCounter(), ql.SimpleThenCompounded, ql.Annual)
```

Where :

```
self.bond  ->  <class 'QuantLib.QuantLib.FixedRateBond'>
bond_dirty_price -> 98.943322
self.yield_curve -> <class 'QuantLib.QuantLib.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle'>
```

This gives me the above TypeError with the message "Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function `BondFunctions_zSpread`."

I expected that the `RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle` could be used in place of a `YieldTermStructureHandle` or `ext::shared_ptr< YieldTermStructure >`, but it seems that this isn't the case. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `self.yield_curve.currentLink()` to retrieve the curve from the handle and pass it to `zSpread`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if the handle did this automatically?

Comment: I suppose we can add an overload.  I'd be careful with implicit conversions.